# How to tell if first Facebook log in - Android

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I am attempting to integrate onboarding screens into my Android application that allows users to register through Email/Password, or through Logging in with Facebook.

Is there any way of programmatically knowing when the user logs in through Facebook whether it is the first time of doing so?

I only want the Onboarding Activity to launch the first time the user logs in through Facebook (after accepting the permissions request), not every time they log in.

Any help with this issue would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: When you login via facebook, facebook asks the user to give authorize your app ([like shown here](https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/uploads/users/362/posts/23837/image/device-2015-04-15-195813.png)). I don't know how facebook apps work, but maybe you can register the first time the user authorizes your app.

Comment: is it not documented for Facebook's API?

Answer (score 0):

use facebook API's to authenticate the users.Login to the facebook developer console to register your application and get the key hashes that will uniquely define your application.

Comment: thanks for the response. I have already successfully implemented the login with facebook feature, I was just wondering if there was a way of telling when the user logged in with Facebook for the first time

Comment: i think the facebook developer console keeps track of the login sessions...this will keep track on first login attempt.....

Answer (score 0):

Use facebook Api by this link https://developers.facebook.com/ register your app.
and follow the instruction as mentioned.Then you can integrate facebook logging in your App